# The "Why are you flagging this post?" input box overflows the dialog.

Tags: bug, status-completed

As you can see from this screen shot:

[image]

The text input box overflows the dialog.

Comment: Aye, repro on Chrome 5, FF 3.5.7 on XP.  IE8 on Win7 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that this is now fixed.

<sup>Now to wait 17! hours to accept the answer - how come the time's just gone up?</sup>